# how to Replace IP Address from in specified file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, ip

I have following script to for this it replaces every ip from specified file but logic is bad

```
while getopts i:h: opt
do
   case $opt in

       i)
    echo "Proposed ip will $OPTARG"
    if [[ $OPTARG =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then

    sed -i 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}$/'$OPTARG'/g' sample.txt 

    echo "proposed ip is $OPTARG"
    else
    echo "fail to update"
    fi ;;

       h) ;;
  esac
done
```

`

want to store all searched IP address in the array replace it how can i do this

input file is

```
ome log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system ip is not found
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system IP is 122.0.0.0
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system IP:122.0.0.0
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
Hostname:ip-172.31.18.255.ec2.internal
some log file entries
some log file entries
```

Comment: You need to share the input file.

Comment: any file that content multiple ip address written

Comment: input file added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution will allow you to store all matched IP addresses in an array and use them elsewhere in your script. From my observations (using your script), all of the ip addresses in your source file were being replaced except the IP address contained in the EC2 private host name. It's not clear if that's what you wanted or not. Below will replace all ip addresses (including the ip contained in the EC2 host name). The regex I'm using was taken from the accepted answer [in this post.](https://superuser.com/questions/202818/what-regular-expression-can-i-use-to-match-an-ip-address)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# Directory where this script is located
#
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

declare ips=()
declare ip_regex='[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
while getopts i:h: opt
do
   case $opt in

       i)
            echo "Proposed ip is $OPTARG"
            if [[ $OPTARG =~ ${regex} ]]; then
                # Store IPs in array for further processingg
                ips=$(echo $(cat "${DIR}/sample.txt") | grep -Eo ${ip_regex})

                for ip in ${ips[@]}; do
                    echo "Replacing '${ip}' with '${OPTARG}'"
                    sed -i 's/'${ip}'/'$OPTARG'/g' "${DIR}/sample.txt"
                done
            else
                echo "Failed to update"
            fi ;;

       h) ;;
  esac
done
```

If you don't want to replace IP addresses contained in the EC2 hostname, a regex (which I constructed from the answer to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186543/how-to-grep-exact-word-with-only-space-as-word-separator)) like the following should work

```
declare ip_regex='(^|[[:space:]])[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}([[:space:]]|$)'
```

Comment: Glad I could help